# Custom UISplitViewController for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to create a custom UISplitViewController for iPad. It is similar to the Facebook iPad version where there is a viewcontroller and a side table view controller, where the table view is the chat group in facebook NOT the Favorites/Group hidden section.

I want to replicate this:

[image]

`2x version here: http://i.imgur.com/0WI5yWo.png`

I would have a UINavigationViewController that has a navigtionItem left side button, a Title, and a right side searchbar. In it's left viewController it will have a viewcontroller that has a mapview and a tableview underneath it. The right viewcontroller will be a tableViewController. There is also a UISegmentedControl above both these viewcontrollers. Anyone have any ideas on how to go about this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Things I have done:

- I have tried using the stock UISplitViewController but I cannot seem to add a UINavigationController to it nor customize it how I want to.
- I think my best option is to have a UIViewController that has 2 ContainerViews. The only problem I can see would be that UISegmentedController as well as how I will have 2 tableviews in one file.

Comment: I've used this before https://github.com/Alterplay/APSplitViewController

Comment: @Hackmodford will that pass Apple's review?

Comment: I have used it in my app.